# How to read a nested JSON key defined in a .json file which was passed using --dart-define-from-file

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running the flutter app using `flutter run --dart-define-from-file=secret.json`.

`secrets.json` file looks like this
`{ "key1": "value1", "key2": { "key3": "value3" } }`

I know that `key1` can be accessed using `String.fromEnvironment("key1")`.

Similarly is there a way to access `key3`?

For example: `String.fromEnvironment("key2.key3")`

Comment: This all changed a few days ago.  Learn about patterns!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dart:convert flutter inbuilt library to decode the JSON string to a Map and then access the nested key and value.

Below I've provided step by step. Follow below steps to solve your problem.

1. Import the dart:convert library

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
```

2. Decode the JSON string to a Map

```dart
final jsonString = String.fromEnvironment('SECRETS');
final Map<String, dynamic> secrets = json.decode(jsonString);
```

3. Access the nested key

```dart
final key3 = secrets['key2']['key3'];
```

you can access "key3" using:

```dart
final key3 = secrets['key2']['key3'];
```

Comment: `String.fromEnvironment("key2")` returns the data `key2: { key3: value3 }`.
json.decode() throws parsing error as `key2` is not enclosed in double quotes ("").

Comment: What is solution of Json parsing problem? I tried to find but did not get any solution for nested dictionary structure